# Why I can not send json string to php with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jplayer

I'm trying to store the following data, taken from a html

```
  title:"Tempered Song",
  artist:"Miaow",
  mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3",
  oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.ogg",
  poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/poster/Miaow_640x360.png"
```

my html code is:

```
<a class="add-music" data-title="Las Voces" data-artist="" href="audios/song-little.mp3">Add to List</a>
<a class="download-music" href="audios/song-little.mp3">Download</a>

<a class="add-music" data-title="Las Voces del Bosque" data-artist="" href="audios/song-little.mp3">Add to List</a>
<a class="download-music" href="audios/song-middle.mp3">Download</a>

<a class="add-music" data-title="Las Bosque" data-artist="" href="audios/song-little.mp3">Add to List</a>
<a class="download-music" href="audios/song-big.mp3">Download</a>
```

and my code jquery is:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.add-music').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'type':'POST',
        'data':fuction() {
          var songNew = JSON.stringify({
            title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
            artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
            mp3: $(this).attr('href'),
          });
        });
        datatype: 'json',
        url: 'session.php',
        async: true,
        cache:false
        });
    });
 });
```

but it does not work, is there any way to make this better and cleaner?

Comment: Please define "does not work". Have you inspected request headers? Have you inspected what the server gets?

Comment: `fuction` is not a valid keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: With the way your data is constructed, nothing will be passed back to the server.

Comment: data is a function? data is the data that you want send, not a function.

Comment: @Curlas: no, not a function. Obviously, that wouldn't work. It is a fuction. I don't know what that is, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end it worked out well

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.add-music').click(function () {
         var songNew = JSON.stringify({
             title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
             artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
             mp3: $(this).attr('href')
         });
         var songIE = {json:songNew};
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: songIE,
             datatype: 'json',
             url: 'session.php',
             async: true,
             cache: false
         });
     });
 });
```

thanks4all

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with how your data is constructed. Use something like the following:

```
'data': JSON.stringify({
      title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
      artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
      mp3: $(this).attr('href'),
 }),
```

This will pass a json encoded string to the server in the post body. If you want the vars to be treated as standard post vars, skip the json encoding step.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your multiple syntax errors:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.add-music').click(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
                 data: function () {
                 var songNew = JSON.stringify({
                     title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
                     artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
                     mp3: $(this).attr('href')
                 });
                return songNew;
             },
             datatype: 'json',
             url: 'session.php',
             async: true,
             cache: false
         });
     });
 });
```

Perhaps better as:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.add-music').click(function () {
         var songNew = JSON.stringify({
             title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
             artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
             mp3: $(this).attr('href')
         });
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: songNew,
             datatype: 'json',
             url: 'session.php',
             async: true,
             cache: false
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: NOTE: As to the content of those attributes in your shown html, some are empty and I don't know how they get populated...but this is the form you should use - or use the `.data()` function perhaps

Comment: @laur - as you are new to SO, welcome! - when you receive and answer that you find acceptable for your question, the proper way is to now click the checkmark on that answer so that it is shown as "answered" by the system and people would not re-answer or seek to, saving them time to address new/other questions.  Glad this worked for you.